# Accumulator for each_with_object keeps re-initializing

Tags: ruby, accumulate

I'm trying to write a generalized cartesian product, where input data of [n1, n2, ...ni] produces output data that is an array of [m1, m2, ...mi] for all mj such that 0 <= mj < nj. I understand the routine below would produce a somewhat folded version of that, but I'm trying to keep the example code as simple as possible. My immediate problem is that the second block variable (accumulator), which I understand is supposed to update for each iteration of the block, is not doing so:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

def gcp(dims)
  first = dims.shift
  dims.each_with_object((0...first).to_a) do |dim, v|
    puts "\nv: #{v}, dim: #{dim}"
    p v.product((0...dim).to_a)
  end
end

gcp([3,2,4])
```

This produces the following output:

```
v: [0, 1, 2], dim: 2
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1]]

v: [0, 1, 2], dim: 4
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]]
```

The `p` method is a passthrough, so the return value of the block should be `[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1]]` on the first iteration, and that should be the value of `v` on the second iteration, unless I gravely misunderstand `each_with_object`.

Comment: Can you show what should be displayed by `p` on the second iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each iteration gets the same object, so you either need to mutate the object inside the block, or use `reduce`.

```
def gcp(dims)
  first = dims.shift
  dims.reduce((0...first).to_a) do |v, dim|
    puts "\nv: #{v}, dim: #{dim}"
    p v.product((0...dim).to_a)
  end
end

gcp([3,2,4])
```

Results in:

```
v: [0, 1, 2], dim: 2
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1]]

v: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1]], dim: 4
[[[0, 0], 0], [[0, 0], 1], [[0, 0], 2], [[0, 0], 3], [[0, 1], 0], [[0, 1], 1], [[0, 1], 2], [[0, 1], 3], [[1, 0], 0], [[1, 0], 1], [[1, 0], 2], [[1, 0], 3], [[1, 1], 0], [[1, 1], 1], [[1, 1], 2], [[1, 1], 3], [[2, 0], 0], [[2, 0], 1], [[2, 0], 2], [[2, 0], 3], [[2, 1], 0], [[2, 1], 1], [[2, 1], 2], [[2, 1], 3]]
```

Comment: I got the same result when replacing `v.product((0...dim).to_a)` with `v = v.product((0...dim).to_a)`, so I assume mutating is different from reassigning. But `reduce` seems simpler anyway. Thankx.

Comment: By "the same result" do you mean the same result as reduce ?

Comment: Lori, `reduce` replaces the value of `v` with the last statement executed in the block. It doesn't matter if that's `product((0...dim).to_a)` or `v = v.product((0...dim).to_a)`, as they are equal, so there's no point in performing the assignment. The only difference between using `reduce` and `each_with _object` is that you need the assignment with the later. Try it. Don't forget the positions of the block variables are reversed with the two methods.

Comment: same result as in my original post

Answer (score 1):

I confess I don't fully understand the question, but I've addressed a similar problem that may explain why `v` is not being updated by your code.

Let's step through your code, returning the desired result rather than displaying it along the way.

```
dims = [3,2,4]

first = dims.shift
  #=> 3 
dims
  #=> [2, 4]     dims
```

The expression

```
dims.each_with_object((0...first).to_a) do |dim, v|
  v.product((0...dim).to_a)
end
```

is effectively the same as

```
v = []
dims.each do |dim|
  v.product((0...dim).to_a)
end
v #=> []
```

That `v` is still an empty array at the end should not be a surprise, as the value of `v` is not altered within the loop. The return value of `v.product((0...dim).to_a)` is shot out into space, never to be seen again. You need an assignment statement within the loop.

Now consider the following.

```
dims = [3,2,4]

v = []
dims.each do |n|
  v << (0...n).to_a
end
v #=> [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

(or `v.push((0..n).to_a)`). To use [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) we would modify the above code by removing the first (`v = []`) and last (`v`) statements, changing `each` to `each_with_object([])` (the argument being the initial value of the object the method will return) and add a block variable `v`, which holds the object:

```
dims.each_with_object([]) do |n,v|
  v << (0...n).to_a
end
  #=> [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

We can simplify this using [Emumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
dims.map do |n|
  (0...n).to_a
end
  #=> [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Depending on your needs, you may prefer using [Emumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map):

```
dims.flat_map do |n|
  (0...n).to_a
end
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Lori, please tell me if I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: The desired output is that obtained by MikeWu, or ultimately, that run through `.map(&:flatten)`